# Displaying JSON data to an outlet in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsonparser

I am extremely new to coding and am trying to learn things one step at a time. I have searched through a stack and found some great ideas but nothing that answers what I am hoping to learn.

I have created some code that pulls JSON weather data from a single web URL. It only shares the weather data for a single location and does not request the information.

I am able to print the information from the JSON data! (This was a huge step). The next step is to display the information that came from the JSON data in my app and on my phone. I have found lots of posts on doing this in table view but have not been able to get that to work for my application, mainly because many of them require you to search for the location to pull the data (which is not applicable in my case).

I am wanting to take one piece of information from the JSON data and display it on my screen.

I have created a label in my storyboard and connect it to my view controller.

I also have weather.swift that calls the JSON data.

The problem I have run into is that I am getting the error "Value of type '[Weather]' has no member 'name'". This is in my view controller.swift on the code line "locationOutlet.text = observationsData.name".

Here is the code in my view controller:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationOutlet: UILabel!

var observationsData = [Weather]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   /* Weather.observations(withLocation: ",") { (results:[Weather]) in
        for result in results {
                print("\(result)\n\n")
        }
       */

    }

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    func loadweatherData (location:String) {

        Weather.observations(withLocation: ",") { (results:[Weather]?) in
                if let weatherData = results {
                    self.observationsData = weatherData
            }

            //let weatherObject = observationsData[IndexPath.row]

    }

    func displayweatherData (location:String) {

        locationOutlet.text = observationsData.name

    }
    //locationOutlet?.text = observationsData.name

}

}
```

and here is the code in weather.swift which calls the JSON data.

```
import Foundation

struct Weather {
    let name:String
    let air_temp:Double
    let wind_spd_kt:Double
    let swell_height:Double


    enum SerializationError:Error {
        case missing(String)
        case invalid(String, Any)
    }

init(json:[String:Any]) throws {
    guard let name = json["name"] as? String else{throw SerializationError.missing("Name is missing")}

    guard let air_temp = json["air_temp"] as? Double else{throw SerializationError.missing("Air temp is missing")}

    guard let wind_spd_kt = json["wind_spd_kt"] as? Double else{throw SerializationError.missing("Wind speed is missing")}

    guard let swell_height = json["swell_height"] as? Double else{throw SerializationError.missing("Swell hight is missing")}

    self.name = name
    self.air_temp = air_temp
    self.wind_spd_kt = wind_spd_kt
    self.swell_height = swell_height
}

static let basePath = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60701/IDN60701.94937.json"

static func observations (withLocation location:String, completion: @escaping ([Weather]) -> ()) {

    let url = basePath //+ location
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

    var observationsArray:[Weather] = []

    if let data = data {

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
            if let currentObservations = json["observations"] as? [String:Any] {
                if let currentData = currentObservations["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for dataPoint in currentData {
                        if let weatherObject = try? Weather(json: dataPoint) {
                            observationsArray.append(weatherObject)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    completion(observationsArray)

    }
}

task.resume()
}

}
```

Clearly, I am learning and trying to do something that might be harder than I really thought. Any assistance on how I can get my label to display the data would be great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It gives you Array of weather why are you showing it in single label?

Comment: Did you just want to print the JSON as it is in that label?

Comment: Great Question! I actually only require the first set of data in the array, the most recent data, but as there was more data in the JSON it made sense to put it in an array. I really only want the information from sort order '0' in the JSON.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping just to print one part of data from the JSON in the label. That's exactly it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then all you have to do is to get the first indexed weather object and display its property in the label.

```
Weather.observations(withLocation: ",") { (results) in
    if let firstIndexWeatherData = results.first {
        //As API calls are usually on background thread and Apple requires Main Thread to update the UI so set your weatherData name to label on main thread like this.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.locationOutlet.text = firstIndexWeatherData.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Syed, I've updated the code and it is giving the error 'expected declaration' in relation to my class. I am guessing that I need to declare something in "class ViewController: UIViewController {"

Comment: Can you paste the entire error text? And also that error occured on which line?

Comment: Thank you, no more error but on compile the label does not display the 'name' from the JSON.

Comment: Set the break point on the line where label is assigning by name. And check the value in `firstIndexWeatherData.name`.

Comment: Or might be JSON-to-Model mapping doesn't set the data correctly.

Comment: Syed! Thank you. After moving things around and attempting to modify things I have my label working! Great solution and thank you for also helping me only call the first set of data in the array. Much appreciated.

Comment: Upvote the answer if you find the solution. So other user can get benefit from it.

Comment: Thank you again. Obviously this is working for a string. The next set of data is a double. How do I call the data of a double to a new object? for example:
self.temperatureOutlet.text = firstIndexWeatherData.air_temp
This gives the error cannot assign value of double to string. Which is obvious. But I don't know how to resolve it. I create a new label called temperatureOutlet too.

Comment: use it in double quotes.

`text = "\(yourDoubleVariable)"`

Comment: Mate, you have been super helpful, and I have something working super basic on my phone. You guys are really great at what you do. I can now start to work on learning more things. Really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We are here to help others in learning and also learn from there mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the array `[Weather].name`
Instead you may want to access `Weather.name`

Try to access one Weather object inside the array